How to move an inner class to its own file
I am using Eclipse. I have class A with an inner class B.
I would like class B to be in its own class file B.java and all references to the class in class A and elsewhere to be updated.
Can someone point me in the right direction for the appropriate refactor please?

On the menu:

Refactor > Move Type to New File...


Thanks. For some reason this wasn't working on the code I was using it on and I ended up doing it manually. It does work on a test case I create though. I don't really have time to figure out why, but good to know this is supposed to work.
